# Having trouble configuring Twilio video settings to maintain FHD screen sharing resolution

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, screensharing, twilio-video

We are building a desktop application for screen sharing. We configured the settings based on the recommendations in this document.
[Developing Applications with collaboration mode](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/developing-high-quality-video-applications#collaboration-mode)

However, the shared screen becomes too blurry to read when some of our users share their screens.
[Shared screen captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fcch.png)

These are the current settings.

```
const room = await Video.connect(token.token, {
  name: 'room-name,
  video: {
    frameRate: 24,
    height: 1280,
    width: 720,
  },
  audio: false,
  bandwidthProfile: {
    video: {
      mode: "collaboration",
      clientTrackSwitchOffControl: "auto",
      contentPreferencesMode: "auto",
    },
  },
  preferredVideoCodecs: [{ codec: "VP8", simulcast: true }],
  networkQuality: { local: 1, remote: 1 },
});
```

We are aware that it depends on a variety of conditions, such as computer resources and network resources. But we feel that this quality adjustment is too much compared to other screen sharing solutions. We want to deliver at least FHD resolution so that users can read text/code. Are there any other settings we should look into or any way to override this automatic quality adjustment function?